# Is there a way to initiate an In-App Purchase from Siri without starting the App but instead run code in the Intents Extension?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, siri

I would like to transact an In-App Purchase from Siri without Siri opening the app to initiate the In-App Purchase. Is this possible?

Specifically, when the user says to Siri, "Search in MyApp", if the user hasn't purchased the feature to search, I want Siri to either show a message from Siri, or show a view with a message, or Siri audibly asks the message, "Would you like to purchase this Search feature as an In-App Purchase?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't transact an in-app purchase with SiriKit. You'll have to have Siri direct the user to open your app to complete the purchase.